How to customize table popup toolbar
I'm developing a React app that includes Jodit for text formatting. I customized the textbox's toolbar by creating a config_new object and assigning it to the config parameter of the JoditEditor component. Here's my React component:
const JoditComponent = ({ textBoxData, handleTextBoxData }) => {
  const editorRef = useRef(null);

  const config_new = {

    //customized settings

  }
    
  return useMemo( () => (
    <div className="jodit-container">
      <JoditEditor
        ref={editorRef}
        value={textBoxData}
        tabIndex={1}
        config={config_new}
        onChange={content => handleTextBoxData(content)}
      />
    </div>), []);
};

export default JoditComponent;

Whenever a table is added, by clicking on one of the cells, a new toolbar pops up. This toolbar is specific for the table that has just been clicked. Here it is:

What should I write in config_new to customize this popup toolbar?

Please don't tag your titles. See [ask].
